# What integer is equal to the expression $\sqrt{50} - \sqrt{18} - \sqrt{8}$?

Tags: arithmetic, radicals

I have no idea how to solve. Is there a formula or something?

Comment: It is equal to $ 5\sqrt{2} -3\sqrt{2} -2\sqrt{2}$  which is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sqrt{50} - \sqrt{18} - \sqrt{8} = 5\sqrt{2} - 3\sqrt{2} - 2\sqrt{2} = 0.$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: $\sqrt{50} = 5\sqrt{2}$. Do the same for the other two radicals.

Answer (score 0):

Since each term is irrational
(being of the form
$d\sqrt{m}$
where
$m=2$ and
 $d$ is a
positive integer),
the only way that
the sum can be rational
is to be zero.

Proof:

If
$a\sqrt{m}+b\sqrt{m}+c\sqrt{m}
= n$,
where $\sqrt{m}$ is irrational,
and $n$ is an integer
then
$a\sqrt{m}+b\sqrt{m}
= n-c\sqrt{m}$.

Squaring,
$m(a+b)^2
=n^2-2nc\sqrt{m}+c^2m
$
or
$2nc\sqrt{m}
=n^2+c^2m-m(a+b)^2
$
which is impossible
since the
left side is irrational
(unless $n=0$)
and the right side
is an integer.

If $n=0$,
then
$c^2=(a+b)^2$
so that
$c = -(a+b)$.